# \ifnum inside \xintfor inside tabular not working

Tags: tables

I'd like to use `\xintfor` for populating a table. I want one multirow cell spanning the same number of rows as elements have a list separated commas.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{xinttools}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{light-cyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{tmpctr}
\setcounter{tmpctr}{0} % Count rows
\rowcolors{2}{light-gray}{light-cyan} 
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
\rowcolor{blue!10}
   {}        &      {}         &     {}        &      {}           & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Multicolumn text}  \\
Column1 & Column2 & Column3 & Column4 & Column5 & Column6\\
\hline
  \xintFor #1 in {SF,LF} \do {
                           \ifnum\value{tmpctr}=1
                             \uppercase{&} text \uppercase{&} text \uppercase{&} text \uppercase{&} text \uppercase{&} text \stepcounter {tmpctr} \\
                           %\else
                           %  \multirow{-2}{*}{multirow text}& text & text & text & text & text \stepcounter {tmpctr} \\
                           \fi 
                           }
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

`\xintfor` works well if I comment out `\ifnum` and `\fi` lines:
[image]
 but when I try to use `\ifnum` inside the loop, using `pdflatex`, I get:

```
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
! Misplaced \noalign.
\hline ->\noalign
                  {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \let \hskip \vskip \let \vrule \hrule \let...
l.30 \hline

?
```

How can I do this?

Next thing would be to remove comments in `\else` and `\multirow` lines, as I want "multirow text" in the two rows of the first column, under "Column 1". I think it should work once I get `\ifnum` working...